# How to do a test with an array of routes in angular?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to do a test that calls by route, but it doesn't work.

on my TS has this array of routes in the menu:

```
  menu(): Array<MenuItem> {
return [
  {
    label: 'Home',
    shortLabel: 'Home',
    action: () => this.router.navigate(['home']),
  },
  {
    label: 'Request',
    shortLabel: 'Requests',
    action: () => this.router.navigate(['request']),
  },
  {
    label: 'About',
    shortLabel: 'About',
    action: () => this.router.navigate(['about']),
  }]
```

I'm trying to take the test like this:

```
  it('menu Home', fakeAsync(() => {
    router.navigate(['home']); 
    tick();
    expect(component.menu).toBe('home');
  }));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Be sure to also specify what exactly does not work, i.e. what is the expected result compared to the actual outcome.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.